# How can I know which file is being used in a bash for loop?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a very tricky question that I have been wanting to tackle for quite some time.

If `$line` is from `$(cat foo)`, then do **action1**

If `$line` is from `$(cat bar)`, then do **action2**

```
for line in $(cat foo) $(cat bar) ; do   
    if [ ??? ]
        then action1
        else action2
    fi
done
```

What would I need to put in the if statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```bsh
for line in $(grep '^.*$' foo /dev/null) $(grep '^.*$' bar /dev/null)
do   
    if [[ ${line} =~ ^foo.*$ ]]
    then
        action1
    else
        action2
   fi
done
```

If you want to strip the leading filename in `$line` afterwards you can add `line=$(<<<$line sed 's/^foo:\(.*\)$/\1/')` and `line=$(<<<$line sed 's/^bar:\(.*\)$/\1/')` in the if / else body.

Comment: Hello kos, thanks for the answer. However, I am getting the error `bash: [: =~: binary operator expected`
I switched line with $line on the if statement. I believe I have found the solution, and I will post it shortly, but I am very open to seeing how yours works too!

Comment: @user264974 You're right sorry, see the update

Comment: Hey kos, I tried the edit, but it is only giving me action2. However, don't even sweat it, thanks for the help

Comment: @user264974 Now it works, I tested it, sorry again. See if it works for you better than your solution. Also if you have found a solution you can just add it as an answer to your own question

Comment: Hey kos, it worked now, thank you. I also put my own answer like you suggested. Stack ex. and its forks are really cool. Most likely I will go with my solution for the mere fact it is pure bash and not dependent on grep, but I have archived your answer for future reference. Once again, thanks and see you around!

Comment: @user264974 `cat` is not really part of `bash` ;) anyway what are you trying to do exactly? If you need a pure `bash` solution maybe I can help, altough per how the question has been asked as of now the "pure `bash`" solution would be *really* ugly.

Comment: Good point! I guess I meant to say, I would like to depend on the least amount of programs as possible. What I am trying to do is for every line in file1 or file2, do a VARIETY of things, and output in either dir1 or dir2. It is a rather large bash script, so instead of copying the script into two scripts, I would rather keep the script as one since I often make changes.
The large script does contain few grep lines I must admit, so either way I am dependent on grep :D

Comment: @user264974 Can't you just split the loop in 2 while loops? Say like `while read -r line; do [...]; done < foo` and `while read -r line; do [...]; done < bar`?

Comment: Hey kos, no the script is much too long for that to be practical. What is going to happen is `for $(cat 1) $(cat 2) [ ... huge script with many commands ... ] if $line was in $(cat 1) ; dir=1 ; else dir=2 ; fi` and then I will have certain things outputted to their intended directories

Comment: @user264974 Than you can define and call a custom function: have a read at [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html), you can define an external function that always takes a string parameter defining the directory and always does what it haves to in such directory

Comment: I have always wondered how functions worked, that cleared it up very easily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23509/discussion-between-tuxforlife-and-kos).

Answer (score -1):

### Self solution

As long as $line will never equal to "FILECHANGE," (most likely never in my case) this will work

```
x=1
for line in $(cat foo) FILECHANGE $(cat bar) ; do
  if [ $line = FILECHANGE ]
  then x=$(($x+1))
  elif [ $x = 1 ]
  then echo 1
  elif [ $x = 2 ]
  then echo 2
  fi
done
```